# Bootstrap 4 Dropdown clone event handled incorrectly

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

My Html Layout

```
<button id="btnClone" type="button">Clone</button>

<div class='dropdown'>
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 2</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="clone"></div>
```

My Javascript

```
$("#btnClone").click(function () {
    var c = $("div.dropdown").clone(true);
    $("#clone").html(c);
});
```

Sample output

[image]

**My problem:**

Every thing is working fine if:

- Click **Clone**
- **Menu 2** is created
- Click either **Menu 1** or **Menu 2**, both dropdown menu expanded correctly

But **NOT** working fine if:

- Click **Menu 1**
- Click **Clone** to create **Menu 2**
- Click **Menu 2**, in this case **Menu 1** is expanded instead.

Comment: try to change id when you clone $('YourItemToClone').clone().attr('id','MyNewClonedId');

Comment: @Neeraj, your code works because of your ``clone()`` without specifying the ``true``. I need a deep copy because I need all the events that I have bind with the menu items.